# Replicate camera and microphone to use across multiple programs

Tags: ffmpeg, virtual, webcam, capture

I'd like to use the same webcam and microphone across multiple streams, for example Google Meets and Microsoft Teams at the same time.

When one of the sources use the webcam/mic, they lock it in and they can't be used anywhere else. Is there a way to replicate or unfreeze them?

I tried via ffmpeg, specificaly by outputting as dshow, but got:

`Requested output format 'dshow' is not a suitable output format`

I also tried this solution: https://superuser.com/a/1531380/934167 but didn't manage to replicate the device.

If possible, I'd like to stick to ffmpeg, but if it requires third party (preferably open source) applications, I can try that out.

Edit: I should also mention, I'd prefer this for Windows/Mac, other solutions were only relevant for linux.